# How to deal with absolute imports when using git submodules

Tags: git, npm, yarnpkg

I have recently added a submodule to a project that uses absolute path in imports

in the submodule:

```
/src/main.js
import Component from 'src/components/Component'
export default ...
```

And in the parent project

```
import Main from 'submodule/src/main'
...
```

that will cause `Unable to resolve module` as src/components/Component doesn't exist. is there any workaround?

Comment: Personally I would not do git submodules. I'd do a local NPM repo and publish to that. Now you will have to deal with all those relative paths.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest not to put these paths fixed into the submodule, but to load these dependencies at runtime instead. That way you can provide the paths when you call them. This pattern is called [dependency injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection)

another solution would be to refactor the submodule so that it doesn't rely on any outside paths at all (this would be the cleanest solution imho, but it's not always possible and efficient)

Here is how you would implement DI in general (Also I just noted that your question is about js, not python. Beside the syntax it should work the same though):

Assuming your SubModule is called "mySubModule" and looks like this:

```py
import myModule

def myFunction(myParameter):
  myModule.doStuff()
```

with Dependency Injection it would look like this:

```py
def myFunction(myModule):
  myModule.doStuff()
```

each time you call `myFunction` you would have to supply the module `myModule` as a parameter. Like this:

```py
import mySubModule
import myModule
mySubModule.myFunction(myModule)
```

You could also do it with a global variable inside your submodule:

```py
myModule = None
def myFunction(myParameter):
  myModule.doStuff()
```

before you call `myFunction` for the first time, you would have to set the module from outside. Like this:

```py
import mySubModule
import myModule
mySubModule.myModule = myModule
mySubModule.myFunction(myModule)
```

If there is a class in your subModule, you could also provide the module as a parameter to the contructor. This would be the cleanest way, I think

Comment: How do I do it with dependency injection exactly?